# Stage3D based 2D Engine with FlashPlayer 10 compatible (or no wmode setting) fallback to software Rendering

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, starling-framework

https://github.com/pshtif/Genome2D/downloads ist the only Stage3D 2D engine with FlashPlayer 10 compatible (no wmode setting) fallback to software Rendering i am aware of.

Unfortunatly they dropped this great feature after 0.35 Version. But i need a Stage3D 2D engine that has such fallback. Any other Engine out there with support for that and active development?

EDIT: Background: I need hardware rendering only on mobile were i can assure a correct set rendering mode. But in the web a lot of game portals do not support any wmode setting. But my game will run fine on a desktop in softwaremode.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think you will find something like this, It would require an 3D engine written completely in ActionScript 3 that has the same capabilities as Stage3D.

Comment: It is not THAT complicated. As shown Genome2D had support for this. You dont need to write an 3D Engine in AS3 just a fallback renderer (e.g. blitting) for 2D Objects

Comment: My apologies, I thought that I had read '3D engine', not 2D.

Comment: I don't think Stage 3D functions, which is mostly available after Flash 11.1+ would be supported in Flash 10.x.
I would use conditional compiling with functions for Flash 10.x and Flash 11.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fork](https://github.com/elsassph/away3dlite-core-fp10) of Away3D Lite does exactly what you want ([complete description here](https://plus.google.com/109524935899218597554/posts/8V4UDWii27e)). It is a 3D engine though. You can overcome that "problem" and make it a 2D engine using a fixed camera and an orthogonal projection.

Comment: It it is not 2D Engine and not in active development, but besides Genome2D-v0.3.5.swc it is probably the closest you can get. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I would not be so optimistic to find an active project that fits all your needs :) Several AS3 engines/frameworks are migrating to Stage3D to take advantage of the GPU.

Comment: I want them to take advantage of Stage3D and GPU, just maintain a software/no wmode fallback !